# Copy part of a paragraph in a variable

Tags: php, text, copy

How can I save a part of the text selected by the mouse in the variable. Is this possible in php? I know it works with javascript, but I want to know if php can do this?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so if you mean copy from a field on the browser, you cannot use PHP you will have to use javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't because `Javascript` is a **client side** but `PHP` is belong to **server side scripting language**

Answer (score -1):

Put an ID in your input and get into php.

```
<input id="myID" type="text" name="myID">
```

in post or get:

```
$yourVariable = $_GET['myID'];
$yourVariable = $_POST['myID'];
```

part of the string:

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // return"d"
echo $rest; // print d
```

This is the only way to do this. If you want to do in the browser, it is only possible using jquery, angular or pure javascript

Comment: This does not answer the question. At least not this question. OP want to get what is selected by the user, not just any part of the string